# Why is this subprocess command not working?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm attempting to remove the first and last comma in each line of multiple `txt` files. When I run the below script, none of the `in_files` are changed (i.e. the commas are still there). What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

I've found the `rev` command from [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60860/removing-the-first-and-the-last-character-of-every-line-from-command-line).

**my script**

```
import subprocess
from glob import glob

in_files = glob('path/to/files/*.txt')

for fyle in in_files:
    rr = f"rev {fyle} | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2-"
    subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', rr])
```

**in_files (file1.txt)**

```
,-0.12000000000000000,0.0000000000000000,
,-0.11889999999999999,0.0000000000000000,
,-0.11780000000000000,0.0000000000000000,
,-0.11670000000000000,0.0000000000000000,
,-0.11559999999999999,0.0000000000000000,
,-0.11449999999999999,0.0000000000000000,
```

**expected**

```
-0.12000000000000000,0.0000000000000000
-0.11889999999999999,0.0000000000000000
-0.11780000000000000,0.0000000000000000
-0.11670000000000000,0.0000000000000000
-0.11559999999999999,0.0000000000000000
-0.11449999999999999,0.0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use an external program, or will this suit your needs?

```
def trim(filename, new_filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        with open(new_filename, "w") as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line.strip(",\n") + "\n")

file_list = ["file1.txt"]
for f in file_list:
    # btw if you want the original file to
    # be overwritten, call `trim(f, f)`
    trim(f, f+"_new.txt")
```

This writes your expected output to the file.

Comment: This works, thanks, but I'd still like to know why my subprocess command isn't working.